# Facing malformed error at Z while trying to convert string to java Date

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to insert the ISO Date into MongoDB using java.
For this, I have tried converting the String to Java Date. But facing "**Invalid Format .The given date is malformed at 'Z'**" exception.
How can I overcome this issue ?

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
        DateTime result;
        Date newResult;
        result = parser.parseDateTime("2014-02-16T00:00:00Z");
        newResult = result.toDate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a different parser in the same class. You have to use the DateTimeParser in ISODateformat for parsing

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser();
DateTime result;
Date newResult;
result = parser.parseDateTime("2014-02-16T00:00:00Z");
newResult = result.toDate();
System.out.println(newResult);
```

This prints : `Sun Feb 16 05:30:00 IST 2014`

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur info.